# "Jetzt dreht der Trainer am ganz großen Rad"

Tags: meaning-in-context

In einem Computerspiel (Fußball) hörte ich den Spruch "***Jetzt dreht der Trainer am ganz großen Rad***". Erst dachte ich, dass gemeint ist, dass er sich extrem aufregt oder "durchdreht". Ein kurze Recherche ergab, dass "am großen Rad drehen" bedeutet, dass man "große Geschäfte macht" oder "sich an großen Vorhaben beteiligt". Allerdings passt das auch nicht direkt. Vermutlich kommt der Spruch nach einer Auswechslung. Bedeutet das wohl, dass eine Auswechslung vollzogen wird, die eine starke Änderung an der Spielweise der Mannschaft bewirkt (Spielsystem), ein besonders guter Spieler ein- oder ausgewechselt wird oder etwas anderes? Oder ist der Spruch einfach nur unpassend?

Comment: Meiner Erfahrung nach sind Kommentare in den Fußballspielen schon immer grottenschlecht gewesen...

Comment: Als ergänzende Info vielleicht noch, dass der Sprecher ein Profi ist (deutscher Fußballkommentator Wolff-Christoph Fuss).

Comment: Das ist unerheblich. Es sind ja keine "Live"-Kommentare. Kann ja auch ein Programmierfehler sein, und der Spruch sollte ganz woanders kommen.

Comment: Nur zur Info: mittlerweile ist klar, dass der Spruch bei einer beliebigen Auswechslung der eigenen oder der gegnerischen Mannschaft kommt (nahezu in jedem zweiten Spiel). Ich finde das nervig und unpassend, aber das ist ja Geschmackssache... Munter bleiben!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ich bin kein Fußball-Experte, aber ich kann mir keine Traineraktion während eines Spiels vorstellen, die diesen Ausdruck rechtfertigen würde. Möglicherweise liegt ein Übersetzungsfehler vor (eines tatsächlich angemessenen idiomatischen Ausdrucks in der Originalsprache) oder der (aus meiner Sicht gelungene) Versuch, das Niveau realer Kommentare bei Fußball-Fernsehübertragungen zu treffen.

Du hast die Bedeutung des Ausdrucks im wesentlichen richtig recherchiert. Ich würde noch ergänzen, daß oft eine deutliche Skepsis mitschwingt, ob der Akteur dem Anspruch seiner Aktion auf Dauer gewachsen ist. Sollte der FC Freiburg die Verpflichtung von Lionel Messi bekanntgeben, wäre "am ganz großen Rad drehen" m.E. ein passender Kommentar. Für die gleiche Aktion seitens des FC Bayern hingegen eher nicht.

Für riskante Auswechslungen (auf einen Schlag 3 Abwehrspieler durch 3 Stürmer ersetzen, den Torwart gegen einen Feldspieler ersetzen) oder eine bedeutende Änderung des Spielsystems könnte man "alle Register ziehen" oder "alles auf eine Karte setzen" verwenden.